# Error in Java Runtime Environment

Tags: linux, java

I was getting below error in CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) while running java application.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f64ff5e0e73, pid=2826, tid=140071723034368
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b17) (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x94ae73]  oopDesc* PSPromotionManager::copy_to_survivor_space(oopDesc*)+0x173
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/local/ProcessListChecker/hs_err_pid2826.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

After executing below command thought problem gets resolved.

`export LD_BIND_NOW=1`

But still getting the error. Need your suggestions!!

Comment: An error report file with more information is saved as:
/usr/local/ProcessListChecker/hs_err_pid2826.log

Comment: Ah, how I love the silence of the lambs.